# Loop through coords

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, minecraft, bukkit

I am working on a SkyBlock, Bukkit java plugin.

I am trying to make so it creates 100 islands in the x then one it reaches 100 is adds one to the z...

Example first island would be (0,0), (1,0)... *100 islands* (0, 1)

But lets say (3, 0) gets deleted i want to fill in that slot

I tried using

```
    private static Vertex2 getNextGrid(int x){
    if(islands.isEmpty()) return new Vertex2(0, 0);
    ArrayList<Island> currentX = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Island island : islands){
        if(island.getGrid().getX() == x)
            currentX.add(island);
    }
    int z = 0;
    ArrayList<Integer> total = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) total.add(i);

    for(Island island : currentX)
        total.remove(island.getGrid().getY());
    if(total.isEmpty())
        getNextGrid(x++);
    return new Vertex2(total.get(0), z);
}
```

But i just get a NullPointerException at *if(island.getGrid().getX() == x)*

Comment: can you show us your `getGrid()` and `getX()` functions?

Comment: @NoamHacker getGrid() just returns a Vector2 and getX() returns an int nothing special

Comment: @Jacob an `int` or an `Integer`?

Comment: @Jobin Just found out the issue was i was adding the new Island object to the list before calling getNextGrid(), so i had an empty island object which was causing .getX() to be null. Would you say my math is correct though? Will the x go to 100 then the next z?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're getting a null pointer, this means that you're trying to invoke a method (or access a field) on an instance that hasn't been set - in the line that you've indicated, there are two places where this may be the case.

1. island - If you have any null values within your islands list, this will cause a null pointer when they are reached. Since we do not know what is being done to islands outside of the snippet, this may well be the case. If nulls are allowed in the list, validate against them when you're looping over it. If not, ensure that nothing can add a null to the list by validating on any methods that add elements to it. If an island is null, the getGrid() call will fail and cause the null pointer.
2. island.getGrid() - If island is not null, the grid may well be. Check that what this method returns can never be null, or validate against it when you're using it.
   Assuming getGrid() has a backing field, make sure the field is initialised rather than just declared, i.e. a value has been set for it.
   If getGrid() is returning null, it will cause the getX() call to fail, and cause the null pointer.